# KolodaView delegate method not working

Tags: ios, swift, swipe

I'm using KolodaView library to create a Tinder-like swipe view: https://github.com/Yalantis/Koloda

I implemented `delegate` method in my `ViewController` like this:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var kolodaView: KolodaView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    kolodaView.dataSource = self
    kolodaView.delegate = self

}

extension ViewController: KolodaViewDelegate {

func koloda(koloda: KolodaView, didSwipeCardAtIndex index: UInt, inDirection direction: SwipeResultDirection) {

    if direction == .Right {
        print("apple")
    } else if direction == .Left {
        print("cherry")
    }
}
}
```

It's supposed to print `apple` or `cherry` when I swipe the card, but it does nothing when I ran it.

Comment: Did you set your `kolodaView.delegate = self`?

Comment: @iSashok I did and my data source methods work fine.

Comment: So try to debug component, add breakpoints in this class https://github.com/Yalantis/Koloda/blob/master/Pod/Classes/KolodaView/KolodaView.swift on line 344 and 345. Did them call?

Comment: @iSashok yeah they got called

Comment: Check your `kolodaView` it should be no nil

Comment: @iSashok I checked, it is nil. But the outlet is connected fine.

Comment: Did you implement methods from `KolodaViewDataSource`?

Comment: @eMKa yeah I did and they work

Comment: with out extension ViewController: KolodaViewDelegate try once

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik it says cannot assign value of type `ViewController` to type `KolodaViewDelegate?`

Comment: Please see my own answer

Answer (score -1, accepted):

OMG you have no idea, this is the most classic/stupid bug I ever made!

Actually, the original code works, it just didn't print in Xcode, because ->

**I ACCIDENTLY DEACITVATED THE CONSOLE!**

After I tried all the methods offered by all the kind people, I finally realized my debug area looked empty like this:

[image]

Then I clicked View -> Debug Area -> Activate Console

Then I finally saw the print :D